# output print/mail with IF and echo command

Tags: if-statement, awk, echo, aix

I want to search 10 maximum size of files in particular folder and if omscb* files is cross the thresh hold it will send mail to people to check and delete those files.
lets assume If out of 10 files 3 files are starting from omscb* . I am using AIX .
for example :-
omscb1 5gb
omscb2 7gb
omscb2 3gb
and other 7 files are not starting with omscb .
So I have wriiten script below but output is coming that last file only which is omscb2 3gb because as per sorting , it is overwriting that current records . Kindly suggest how to get all the file names in output .

```
THRESHOLD="5"
LOG=/home/log1.txt
cd /home/var/log
du -sg *|sort -r|head -10 | awk '{print $1"\t"$2}' | while read LINE; do
PERC1=`echo $LINE |awk '{print $1}'`
PERC2=`echo $LINE |awk '{print $2}'`
if [ $PERC1 -gt  $THRESHOLD ] || [ "$PERC2" = omscb* ] ;then
#echo $PERC1 $PERC2 \n >> ${LOG}
fi
done

print $LOG
```

==============
Thanks in advance .

Comment: You should install `GNU!find`; the default `AIX!find` has very limited functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the majority of the logic can be encapsulated into one awk statement

```
du -sg /home/var/log |sort -r|head -10 | awk -v thresh="5" -v logfile="/home/log1.txt" '{ if ($1 > thresh | $2 ~ "omscb") { print $1" "$2 >> logfile;close(logfile) } }'
```

Pipe the output of the sorted du command into awk and pass the logfile and threshold as variables to use within the awk statement. If the first space delimited field is greater than the variable thresh, or the second field pattern matches "omscb" print the first and second fields separated by a space to the logfile and close it.